# Exit the editing state after performing a search with Search Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a search controller in order to implement a search section in an iOS app. I'm using iOS 11 and xCode 10.

My scene is a Table View Controller. I have included a search bar programmatically with the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

I have also included a UISearchBar delegate extension:

```
extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    tableView.reloadData()

    episodeResultsArray = []

    let searchTerm = searchBar.text!
    let escapedSearchTerm = searchTerm.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    performSearch(forTerm: escapedSearchTerm)
}
}
```

The performSearch function connects to a database via AlamoFire and returns the results which are then listed in the Table View.

When I run the app, the table appears empty (as it should be initially). When I click on the search bar, it enters the editing state (the navigation bar collapses, the search bar sticks to the top, a Cancel button appears, and a translucent grey box covers the rest of the screen.

When I search for something, the results are succesfully listed in the table. However, even though the results are visible, I still remain in the editing state for the search bar. I need to click on the translucent box to exit the editing state and only then I am able to scroll through the results.

How can I exit the editing state after I click on Search so I'm able to scroll through the table as soon as I get the results?

I tried using searchBar.resignFirstResponder() but this only dismisses the keyboard. I also tried

```
searchBar.endEditing(true)
```

but even though the search bar loses focus, I'm still in the editing state.

Just to clarify, I need for this to work as a search from scratch, not as a filter, meaning not just showing a subset of results as I type.

Comment: Try this self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. The search box loses focus but I need to exit the editing stage.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. The solution is to add

```
searchController.isActive = false
```